# nginx enabling CORS for multiple subdomains

Tags: nginx

My nginx version: nginx/1.4.6

I have an issue enabling CORS for multiple subdomains. I checked https://gist.github.com/algal/5480916 and http://rustyrazorblade.com/post/2013/2013-10-31-cors-with-wildcard-domains-and-nginx/ but both solutions doesn't work for me.

It looks like the regex

```
if ($http_origin ~* (.*\.mydomain.com)) {
    set $cors "true";
}
```

is not matching and $cors is not set to "true" and therefor add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin" won't be executed.

I also tried with regex

> $http_origin ~* (https?://.*.mydomain.com)

or

> $http_origin ~* https?://.*.mydomain.com

But in either case the regex doesn't match and $cors will never set to "true".

What am I missing?

My nginx configuration - domain name in curly braces (is getting replaced by Ansible):

```
upstream varnish {
  server localhost:80;
}

server {
    listen 443 default;
    server_name {{vhost}};

    ssl                  on;
    ssl_certificate      /etc/ssl/certs/ssl.{{domain}}.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /etc/ssl/private/{{domain}}.key;

    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    #ssl_ciphers  ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP;
    #ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

    # workaround remote exploit. Fixed in 1.5.0, 1.4.1
    #
    # http://mailman.nginx.org/pipermail/nginx-announce/2013/000112.html
    if ($http_transfer_encoding ~* chunked) {
        return 444;
    }

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;

    proxy_redirect off;

    # CORS
    set $cors "";
    if ($http_origin ~* (.*\.{{domain}})) {
        set $cors "true";
    }

    location / {
            # Set the max size for file uploads (/admin, /webmail)
            client_max_body_size 10G;

            proxy_pass http://varnish;
            if ($cors = "true") {
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin";
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow_Credentials' 'true';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,Accept,Origin,DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range, X-CSRF-Token';
                add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET,POST,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE,PATCH';
            }

            if ($request_method = OPTIONS) {
                return 204;
            }

    }

    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }

}
```

Comment: could you show us how the config looks like when Ansible replaced the variables?

Comment: Did you test it with a POST instead of a GET? See my answer below!

Answer (score 26):

There are some unexpected things that occur when using `if` inside location blocks in NGINX. It's not recommended. Here is a solution that uses `map`. https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/ and https://agentzh.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-nginx-location-if-works.html

This setup allows me to make requests to any subdomain and any port on my-domain.com and localhost (for development).

```
map $http_origin $allow_origin {
    ~^https?://(.*\.)?my-domain.com(:\d+)?$ $http_origin;
    ~^https?://(.*\.)?localhost(:\d+)?$ $http_origin;
    default "";
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' $allow_origin;
    add_header Vary Origin; 
    # ...
}
```

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html

Note:

> the server should also include Origin in the Vary response header to indicate to clients that server responses will differ based on the value of the Origin request header.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#access-control-allow-origin

Comment: Any idea how one would implement this with `more_set_headers`?

Answer (score 6):

You can get around the limitation of only one subdomain by using this clever workaround that will allow all subdomains:

```
server {

    root /path/to/your/stuff;

    index index.html index.htm;

     set $cors "";

    if ($http_origin ~* (.*\.yoursweetdomain.com)) {
        set $cors "true";
    }

    server_name yoursweetdomain.com;

    location / {

        if ($cors = "true") {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin";
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'User-Agent,Keep-Alive,Content-Type';
        }


        if ($request_method = OPTIONS) {
            return 204;
        }

    }
}
```

Credit: http://rustyrazorblade.com/post/2013/2013-10-31-cors-with-wildcard-domains-and-nginx/

Comment: did you read my original post/question? In my first phrase I mentioned that this link/source doesn't work for me.

Comment: Nginx `if` is [evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/).

Comment: After 48hours of stalling because of a CORs issue. this worked for me! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

its been a year but, here is the solution that worked for me.

```
location / {
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  
    # Nginx doesn't support nested If statements, so we
    # concatenate compound conditions on the $cors variable
    # and process later

    # If request comes from allowed subdomain
    # (*.mckinsey.com) then we enable CORS
    if ($http_origin ~* (https?://.*\.mckinsey\.com(:[0-9]+)?$)) {
       set $cors "1";
    }
  
    # OPTIONS indicates a CORS pre-flight request
    if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
       set $cors "${cors}o";
    }
  
    # Append CORS headers to any request from 
    # allowed CORS domain, except OPTIONS
    if ($cors = "1") {
       more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: $http_origin';
       more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true';
       proxy_pass      http://serverIP:serverPort;
    }
  
    # OPTIONS (pre-flight) request from allowed 
    # CORS domain. return response directly
    if ($cors = "1o") {
       more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: $http_origin';
       more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE';
       more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true';
       more_set_headers 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin,Content-Type,Accept';
       add_header Content-Length 0;
       add_header Content-Type text/plain;
       return 204;
    }
  
    # Requests from non-allowed CORS domains
       proxy_pass      http://serverIP:serverPort;
  }
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/bramswenson/51f0721dec22b9b258aea48b59e9a32c

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the check for `$http_origin` into your `location` block.

You can see the same in the first example link you gave.

The variable is probably first filled when the `location` block is called.

Comment: moving the check for $http_origin into your location block doesn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

`$http_origin` contains the value of the "origin" field in the request header.

The reason why you might have the impression that it does not work is that you tested it with a request where the "origin" header field is **empty**. Example: **Browsers do not set the origin field on GET requests**, only on POST and maybe more...

For exact info, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42239643/when-do-browsers-send-the-origin-header-when-do-browsers-set-the-origin-to-null

So, **the code above works perfectly OK** because your GET requests do not need the CORS fields in the response header. GET works without those fields!